# How to load a different view to detail view in split view iOS

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

I was wondering how I can load a different view into the detailView from rootview..

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

            //[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES]; 

        }


}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: well.. i have a splitViewController and it comes with rootViewController, and detailViewController. and i wanna load a different viewcontroller into the detailViewController when a row is selected..

Answer (score 4):

**The `splitviewcontroller` has an array of 2 views one is root view and another one is detail view,and you can change the views in this array. If you alloc and init a view and replace it with either of these two then this view will replace the current view in the `splitviewcontroller`.**

Use this code for loading different views for different cells of rootview. Change rootview's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method as follow:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UIViewController  *localdetailViewController = nil;

    if (indexPath.row==0)
    {

    DetailViewController *detailView=[[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];

    localdetailViewController=detailView;

    detailView=nil;

    }

    if (indexPath.row==1)
    {

    SecondViewController *secondDetailView=[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    localdetailViewController=secondDetailView;
    secondDetailView = nil;
    }

    UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    [navController pushViewController:localdetailViewController animated:YES];

    YourSplitViewAppDelegate *delegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSArray *viewControllers=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[delegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0],navController,nil];

    delegate.splitViewController.viewControllers = viewControllers;

    [localdetailViewController release];

    [navController release];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks it works correctly except my master view controller is not hiding after I select the cell from table view. Any idea whats going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using Using Xcode 7.1.1 for a universal app, using Storyboards, Auto Layout and Size Classes, building for iOS 9...

I used a version of [Midhun MP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12017225/1883707)... within the current/original (not replacement/new/second) detail view controller's `viewDidLoad` method:

obviously first import the correct header file for your controller:

```
#import "NEW_DetailViewController.h"
```

then within `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    <<OTHER_CODE>>

    if (<<INSERT_THE_LOGIC_YOU_NEED_TO_TRIGGER_THE_REPLACEMENT_DETAIL_VC>>) {
        NEW_DetailViewController *viewNewDetailVC = [[NEW_DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NEW_DetailViewController" bundle:nil];

        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        [navController pushViewController:viewNewDetailVC animated:YES];

        NSArray *arraySplitViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0],navController,nil];

        self.splitViewController.viewControllers = arraySplitViewControllers;
    }
}
```

**NOTE** I could make this code work without loading a XIB file, building the entire replacement detail VC in code, with `[[UIViewController alloc] init]` instead of `[[NEW_DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NEW_DetailViewController" bundle:nil]`, but was frustrated that I could not make the XIB file load, so I persisted...

I attempted many variations from many different SO answers in attempting to solve this problem of successfully loading a XIB file as the replacement detail view controller in a split view controller.

Finally [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28438798/1883707) by [Travis M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1446573/travis-m) gave me the hint I needed...

Delete all the efforts you have attempted to date to create a new XIB file and subclass of `UIViewController`!

Create a new file and make it a subclass of UIViewController. See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of new subclass of new UIViewController]

**IMPORTANT** ensure you check the checkbox "Also create XIB file".

You don't need to modify the new subclass of `UIViewController`, unless you'd like to code up the contents of the view. I only needed to add in a `UILabel` for my solution and I did this using Interface Builder.

Make sure you reference the replacement view controller `NEW_DetailViewController` in code as per my example above.

That's it!

In your XIB file you should end up with the following:

[image: Files Owner -> subclass: NEW_DetailViewController]

[image: Files Owner -> Outlet:view]

[image: View -> Referencing Outlet:view]